# Updating array values for a particular id in database

Tags: php, mysql

Im working on a web application where i need to let users update several tds in a tr of a table. As of now i can fetch and show the database values in the respective td's. But when i try to update them, the last entered values in the last tr gets updated for all the td's in the table.

Below is the part of the query im trying. All the values are considered array since values are gathered from several input box.

```
$cno="123";
$c  = count($ndv);
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++)
{

$query_dv="UPDATE device SET cid = '$cno',name = '$ndv[$i]',type = '$tdv[$i]',serialno = '$sdv[$i]',model = '$mdv[$i]',location = '$ldv[$i]'  WHERE cid = ".$cno;

$sql_device = mysqli_query($conn, $query_dv) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

}
```

so say right now i try to update with values 123,1,1,1,1,1 and 123,2,2,2,2,2

i get 123,2,2,2,2,2 and 123,2,2,2,2,2 .. i do understand that its getting reupdated due to the for loop. So im trying to fix this part of the code. And im struggling to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its because of your where clause at the end of you statement,  `WHERE cid = ".$cno;` you are just updating the row where `cid = 123` every iteration of your loop, the value of `$cno` should change as you loop through

Comment: but i have to update the values based on the `cid` value..i mean.. for cid = 123, there are several columns and rows of values from the td of the table. so im trying to update those values for a particular cid value. hope u understood

Comment: Yes, but the `cid` for each row is unique correct? you're just selecting where it equals 123 over and over again

Comment: its not unique..its just an another column in the table.. where for a particular cid value, there are multiple entries .. it may or maynot be duplicate values. so the cid is not defined with a primary or a unique key

Comment: Then you should uniquely identify the `tr==row` you are wanting to update so like `WHERE cid = ".$cno ." AND id = " . $id[$i]` or even just use `$i`

Comment: i have created an id column in the database which is unique and auto increments and in the page where i fetch data from the database, i have created a td which is disabled and displays the id value for that row from the database and made it as an array using the name attribute.. In the update script this array value will be used in the update query as you suggested. is this the right way to do ? or is there any other simple way to do without beating around the bush. As of now it works.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested and it appears to work. Will test few more and let you know. Thank you :)

Comment: I'd say it's the correct way as the sql needs to now which unique row you are wanting to update, if what I said has solved your issue I'll add it as an answer now.

Comment: A PK is essential. But I'm not quite sure that I understand the proposed implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are not uniquely identifying the row you are wanting to update, todo this add a column to your database called something like `id` make it the primary key and have it auto increment, then in your table add a hidden/disabled input containing the id and update your query to be something along the lines of

```
 $query_dv="UPDATE device SET name = '$ndv[$i]',type = '$tdv[$i]',serialno = '$sdv[$i]',model = '$mdv[$i]',location = '$ldv[$i]'  WHERE id = " . $id[$i];
```

I removed the update for `cid` because from your question it doesn't look like it changes so no need to update.